# How to display binary images into a gridview in ASP.NET using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

I want to display binary images into a gridview named 'gvExistedCharacter'. I did research about it and many of them suggested to use a handler. However, I have no idea how can I do about it.

FYI: The datatype of the image in the database is image and named 'blueBallImage'. I also want to display its level which is int in the same gridview.

I have tried

```
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=MyCloudGames;Integrated Security=True");

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select blueBallImage FROM CorrespondingBall", con);
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = con;

    SqlParameter ImageID = new SqlParameter("@characterID", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
    ImageID.Value = context.Request.QueryString["characterID"];
    cmd.Parameters.Add(ImageID);
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    dReader.Read();
    context.Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])dReader["Image"]);
    dReader.Close();
    con.Close();
```

I received an error **"The parameterized query '(@characterID int)Select blueBallImage FROM CorrespondingBall' expects the parameter '@characterID', which was not supplied."**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use handler to display image in gridview , your html markup look like inside

`Gridview   ItemTemplate`  set image control src  as `src=~/ShowImage.ashx?id=" + id`

where `ShowImage.ashx` is your handler which return MemoryStream((byte[])img);

In your case your querystring is `characterID`

so your image src would be  `src=~/ShowImage.ashx?id=" + characterID`

---

**Updated Answer:**

**Html Markup:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CharacterID">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblid" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("characterID") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="GameLevel">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblglevel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("gameLevel") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#"ShowImage.ashx?getID="+Eval("characterID") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**Code behind:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    DataTable dt = getData();
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
  }

public  DataTable getData() 
{
  SqlDataAdapter dap = new SqlDataAdapter("select characterID,blueBallImage,gameLevel from CorrespondingBall", cn);
  DataSet ds = new DataSet();
  dap.Fill(ds);
  return ds.Tables[0];
}
```

**Generic handler:** Add new generic handler here showIamges.ashx is my generic handler

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
 {
    Int32 my_Id;
    if (context.Request.QueryString["getID"] != null)
    {
       my_Id = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.QueryString["getID"]);
       context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
       Stream strm = ShowEmpImage(my_Id);
       byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
       int byteSeq = strm.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);
       while (byteSeq > 0)
        {
           context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, byteSeq);
           byteSeq = strm.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);
        }
      }
}

public Stream ShowEmpImage(int my_Id)
{
   string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
   SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conn);
   string sql = "select blueBallImage from CorrespondingBall WHERE characterID = @ID";
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", my_Id);
   connection.Open();
   object img = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
   return new MemoryStream((byte[])img);
 }
```

Comment: Hi Satinder, I would like to ask you a question. What is @ characterID actually? I saw some of the tutorials where they put something like @ ID and etc. Pardon me for that as I have not used handler before.

Comment: id reperesnt of which row you want to show image ? there might be some relation , i.e like  employeID,,empname,employe_image  column so in gridview you binddata  id,name,image

Comment: I still cannot get it. What if I want to display every images for blueBallImage?

Comment: @LiuJiaHui: blueBallimage is your colmn name right, then it has many rows many, for each row you need to set respective image, if you still have trouble let me know

Comment: blueBallImage is my column name and it have many rows which contain a image. How can I display it all out?

Comment: @LiuJiaHui: you only want to display image, not any other column filed ?? how your gridview look like ???

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38473/discussion-between-liu-jia-hui-and-satinder-singh)

Comment: DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'characterID'. What does it means? This error was found in <asp:Label ID="lblid" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("characterID") %>'></asp:Label>

Comment: as you said you have these colmns characterID,gamelevel,blueballimage so characterID is your first col name

Comment: It is working now! I have entered the wrong variable. Thank you very much!

Comment: can you have a look here and answer [link] (http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1028453/display-binary-image-in-asp-net-grid-using-dataset?arn=0)

Answer (score 0):

You want to add `@characterID` parameter to your sql command but your command doesn't have a parameter called `@characterID`.

Remove your parameter process in your code or add @characterID in your sql command which try to match.

Comment: Hi Soner, I want to display all blueBallImage images out. May I know how can I do it?