# How to solve NULL value for image

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have redImage and whiteImage in my database table colourGame. Their datatype is image. And also, binary image. I want to display them in a gridview.

```
SqlDataAdapter da= new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT 
                                         ballID,
                                         gameLevel,
                                         gameChapter,
                                         redImage,
                                         whiteImage 
                                      from 
                                         colourGame 
                                       WHERE 
                                         gameLevel = '"+ ddlLevel.Text+"' 
                                         AND gameChapter = '"+ddlChapter.Text+"' ", cn);
```

ddlLevel and ddlChapter are dropdownlist.

```
ddlLevel.Items.Add("3");
        ddlLevel.Items.Add("4");


        ddlChapter.Items.Add("1");
        ddlChapter.Items.Add("2");
        ddlChapter.Items.Add("3");
        ddlChapter.Items.Add("4");
        ddlChapter.Items.Add("5");
```

In my database table data, if redImage have image, whiteImage will be NULL and vice versa.

Therefore I experienced an error regarding null value.

Comment: If redImage is NULL, whiteImage have image. While redImage have image, whiteImage is NULL.

Comment: Why not just store it in an `image` column and add a `side` char column which you set to `R(ed)` or `W(hite)`?

Comment: If that is the case, there would be a lot of work to be done as this is link to my game in Windows Phone. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you just took care of the null in the database and only returned the valid image?

Note the coalesce in the query.  This will return only the first non null value.

EDIT: (coalesce to an empty string instead of second image)

```
SqlDataAdapter da= new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT 
                                     ballID,
                                     gameLevel,
                                     gameChapter,
                                     coalesce(redImage,'') as [redImage],
                                     coalesce(whiteImage, '') as [whiteImage]
                                  from 
                                     colourGame 
                                   WHERE 
                                     gameLevel = '"+ ddlLevel.Text+"' 
                                     AND gameChapter = '"+ddlChapter.Text+"' ", cn);
```

The comment about SQL injection is a real one, you need to [parameterize this query](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Query_Parameterization_Cheat_Sheet).

EDIT#2: Handle your error.  This is untested, but test `img` to see if its DBNull or not.

```
return new MemoryStream((byte[])img);
```

Change to:

```
If(img.GetType() == typeof(System.DBNull)) return new MemoryStream();
return new MemoryStream((byte[])img);
```

Comment: Hi paqogomez, I still received the same error "Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.Byte[]'." in my handler. In this project, I need to have a NULL in redImage and a image in whiteImage and vice versa.

Comment: Clearly you dont want a Null, its the null that is giving you the problem.  See my edits for another solution idea.

Comment: @LiuJiaHui  Make sure you dont miss the comma's that I added.

Comment: Thank you paqogomez. But the same error still occurred.

Comment: @LiuJiaHui You need to post more code then. You are only showing the sql, so we can only help w/ the sql.  Post your drop down list code.

Comment: I have edited, do take a look.

Comment: @LiuJiaHui What is the exact error you are receiving?

Comment: The error is "Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.Byte[]'" in my Generic Handler when "return new MemoryStream((byte[])img);"

Comment: You may like to take a look at the handler codes and others at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132451/how-to-display-binary-images-into-a-gridview-in-asp-net-using-c

Comment: @LiuJiaHui I changed my code to reflect the new info.  You should post all the code that is throwing the error, instead of this supporting stuff.

Comment: I am sorry about it. From your latest solution, I am experiencing an error on System.DBNull. 'System.DBNull' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'.

Comment: Thank you! It is working now. I have one last question. Now the no data images are display as a cross image. How can I display it as blank instead?

Comment: @LiuJiaHui that sounds like a new question.  Please mark as answer and post another.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

You can probably write it as:

```
<asp:Image ID="imgWhite" Url='<%# Eval("Image") == DBNull.Value ? "" : Eval("Image") %>'></asp:Image>
```

First of all, read about [SQL INjections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

On Rowdatabound you will have to bind that image and drop downs to gridview, then only it will show.

Eg.

```
    protected void gvUserInfo_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
    DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)gvUserInfo.FindControl("yourControlName");
    string ddlValue = ddl.SelectedItem.Value;
    TextBox txtUserInfo = (TextBox) gvUserInfo.FindControl("yourControlName");
    string strValue = txtUserInfo.Text;
    Image imgCtrl = (Image) args.Row.FindControl("imgCtrl");
    imgCtrl.ImageUrl = m_ConcatUrl;
    }
```

In the same way you will have to bind image.

Comment: Hi Shrimant! If redImage is NULL, whiteImage have image. While redImage have image, whiteImage is NULL. Therefore, "Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.Byte[]'." in my handler. How can I solve the null value? I want it to be blank in my gridview.

Answer (score 0):

you should try IsNULL().

```
SqlDataAdapter da= new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT 
                                     ballID,
                                     gameLevel,
                                     gameChapter,
                                     IsNULL(redImage,'')[redImage],
                                     IsNULL(whiteImage,'')[whiteImage] 
                                  from 
                                     colourGame 
                                   WHERE 
                                     gameLevel = '"+ ddlLevel.Text+"' 
                                     AND gameChapter = '"+ddlChapter.Text+"' ", cn);
```

Comment: Hi Vikash, your solution is not working. The same error still occurred.

Comment: Do you have any idea about how to set a null image value to '0'? In my handler, it is returning me image value, however, if it is null, the error will occurred.

Comment: then you have to handle it manually at grid view. check if image column is giving null then do not bind any image to Image Control. **<asp:Image ID="imgWhite" Url='<%# Eval("whiteImage") == DBNull.Value ? "" : Eval("whiteImage") %>'></asp:Image>**