# Show Image in Sql databse to Rad Grid

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, telerik, telerik-grid

I want to show the images stored in Sql Server DB in binary format to show in RAD grid in Asp.net VB something like this example. 
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/lightbox/examples/overview/defaultvb.aspx

Can you help?

Comment: here is a link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132451/how-to-display-binary-images-into-a-gridview-in-asp-net-using-c

Answer (score 1):

I do not see the point of your question. However, the source code of that particular link is here:
[aspx](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/lightbox/examples/overview/defaultvb.aspx?#qsf-demo-source)