# How to show images in a row in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, gridview

I want to  show Images in gridview in a row. Because gridview shows every record in column. Just like a photo album in which photos are shown side by side, I also want to show pictures like that.

What should I do for this? Should I use any css?

Below is my Gridview code

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvImages" CssClass="Gridview" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#7779AF" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="white">

 <Columns>

 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image">

 <ItemTemplate>

 <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "ThumbNail.ashx?photoid="+ Eval("Photo_ID") %>' Style="cursor: pointer" OnClientClick = "return LoadDiv(this.src);" Height="200px" Width="200px"/>

 </ItemTemplate>

 </asp:TemplateField>

 </Columns>

 </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: you might be missing `Server.MapPath` for ImageUrl.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132451/how-to-display-binary-images-into-a-gridview-in-asp-net-using-c

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Try using this */
style{
display:inline-block; 
width:200px; 
height:200px;
float:left;
margin:1px;
}
```

Comment: ok I replaced grid to datalist and it solved my problem by adding property RepeatDirection="Horizontal"